# App crashes when trying to highlight text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

On long press and hold gesture to highlight text, the app crashes and I get this stacktrace from sentry https://suditeq.sentry.io/share/issue/f0eb0879711d439ba8d73b87e02ffcf9/

```
SelectionContainer {
                                    Column(
                                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
                                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                                    ) {
                                        Text(
                                            text = stringResource(R.string.etymology),
                                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
                                        )
                                        Text(
                                            text = it.first().etymology!!,
                                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge
                                        )
                                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use try catch around it so that you can better understand the error.

Comment: I would do that, but I can't replicate locally. Error seems to occur only in production

Comment: Is the error occuring on multiple different devices or is it just this one occurance?

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif multiple devices

Comment: It requires a lot of debugging and information to understand the problem as to which devices, android versions, and libraries are producing this error. is it a memory issue or heap size  etc. I have very little info to go on; so all I can say for now as is that apply exception handling even through try catch to stop the app from crashing and in the catch block you can send debug logs to your server that will lead you to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably hitting an instance of this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289777673. Looks like it's happening when R8 is enabled, and there's a workaround mentioned to exclude the text selection classes from minification:

```
-keep class androidx.compose.foundation.text.selection.** { *; }
```

Not sure, if you can do much more than that, maybe ping the issue that you're also having this problem and someone at Google will revive it.

Comment: would follow on the issue